# Sql query with where clause having is null and case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
DECLARE @AuditTypeID BIGINT=NULL
DECLARE @ChecklistTypeID BIGINT = NULL


SELECT * FROM TmpChecklist WHERE ChecklistTypeID IN 
          (CASE WHEN (@AuditTypeID IS NOT NULL) THEN (select distinct ChecklistTypeID from TmpChecklist where checklistTypeID IN 
                (SELECT checklistTypeID FROM TmpChecklist WHERE AudittypeID=@AuditTypeID AND (@ChecklistTypeID IS NULL OR @ChecklistTypeID = '') 
                UNION SELECT @ChecklistTypeID))
                ELSE
                (SELECT DISTINCT checklistTypeID FROM TmpChecklist WHERE checklistTypeID IN (ISNULL(@checklistTypeID,checklistTypeID) ))
          END)
```

Here both variables can be null or either can be null or both can be not null

So if `@AuditTypeID` is not null then I want to select `ChecklistTypeID` based on `@AuditTypeID` otherwise select all `ChecklistTypeID` (again if `@ChecklistTypeID` is null then select all `ChecklistTypeID`  otherwise based on `@ChecklistTypeID` )

I was trying above query but something is wrong.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you want is a bit simpler than what you are doing:

```
SELECT cl.*
FROM TmpChecklist cl
WHERE (@AuditTypeID IS NULL OR cl.AudittypeID = @AuditTypeID) AND
      (@ChecklistTypeID IS NULL OR cl.ChecklistTypeID = @ChecklistTypeID);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use case in where clause,you can write your query like below

```
DECLARE @AuditTypeID BIGINT=NULL
DECLARE @ChecklistTypeID BIGINT = NULL


SELECT * FROM TmpChecklist WHERE  (@AuditTypeID IS NOT NULL and
ChecklistTypeID IN  
(select distinct ChecklistTypeID from TmpChecklist where 
 checklistTypeID IN 
                (SELECT checklistTypeID FROM TmpChecklist WHERE AudittypeID=@AuditTypeID
                                        AND (@ChecklistTypeID IS NULL OR @ChecklistTypeID = '') 
                UNION SELECT @ChecklistTypeID)
))
                OR
ChecklistTypeID in
                (SELECT DISTINCT checklistTypeID FROM TmpChecklist WHERE checklistTypeID IN coalesce(@checklistTypeID,checklistTypeID))
```